# SQL query with variable ,IF & select staement

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I create an SQL select query to return variable as true(1) if a column value exists in a table else false(0). 
I want to use this variable in my scripts so that

if variable=1 
execute A
ELSE 
execute B

Comment: Use a CASE expression.  BTW, it would be helpful if you showed sample table, and expected outputs.  Your question is somewhat vague.

Comment: Which database are you using, MySQL or Oracle?  Please provide sample input and desired results as well to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle you can use something like this

```
    SELECT
    CASE nvl(length(column1), 0)
    WHEN 0 THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END AS column1
    FROM yourTableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName WHERE FieldName = 'Whatever') <> 0) 
-- Execute something if column value exists
ELSE
-- Execute something if column value does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tableName WHERE fieldName='value') THEN 1;
            ELSE 0;
       END
INTO variable
--that is PostgreSQL